# Without let before name - TypeError: name.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, reserved-words

If I don't use `let` or `var` before allocation to my varaiable `name` I get a **TypeError: name.map is not a function**
Is name a reserved word or anything else. If so I'm wondering why I don't get any error at the allocation `name = [ ... ];`
Can anybody give me some more information about this behaviour.

```js
name = ["apple", "orange", "strawberry", "banana"];
result = name.map(elem => elem.toUpperCase() );
console.log(result);
```

If I put let or var before it works as desired.

```js
let name = ["apple", "orange", "strawberry", "banana"];
result = name.map(elem => elem.toUpperCase() );
console.log(result);
```

By all other variable-names the global use of it isn't any problem although usually better to avoid.

```js
other = ["apple", "orange", "strawberry", "banana"];
result = other.map(elem => elem.toUpperCase() );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `name` without declaration refers to `window.name` property, which is type-protected (it's always a string). Just don't use undeclared variables, also globals have to be declared.

Comment: I didn't know that properties could be type-protected in JS.

Comment: [`'use strict';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid in the future to omit `let`, `var`, `const`...

Comment: Well, kinda "_type-protected_", it's a native property, though. You can create a "type-protected" variable using getters and setters.

Comment: Normally I use `let`, `var` or  `const`. But this was a code-snippet from someone-other here which I used to improve his problem, so I didn`'t look for this and there I get this problem. So you are right `use strict`is a good practice.